# Excel 2010 open SharePoint file behaves differently from two client PC

Tags: excel, sharepoint

There are two client PCs.  PC1 has only Office 2010 installed and PC2 has multiple Office installed but office 2010 is the default installation.

The two PCs behaves strangely when open SharePOint Excel file.  No files are checked out from SharePoint and no one is trying to access the same file at the same time.  PC1 opens Excel file from SharePOint is read-only (don't have Check out button under File-> Versioning).  PC2 opens Excel file from SharePOint is ok to edit (does have Check out button under File-> versioning, can add a new row and save directly).

What cause the check out button shown differently on different PCs even the files are in the same condition in the Share Point?

Added Notes here: I think this is totally related to the first PC.  The first time (only the first time/can be edited in the second time) to open Excel file from client application side has the issue.  I have checked Content.MSO and did see all files created and removed correctly so it is not Content.MSO issue.

Thanks,
YK